# (JS) Sumir com um botão de submit form depois de clicado

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se tem como escoder um botão "submit" de uma form. Eis a minha situação:

Não tenho acesso ao HTML, pois é um aplicação Drupal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um script que checa o localStorage do navegador e caso a página ja tenha sido visitada ele some com o botão. O problema é que o botão sumia para sempre.

```
var visita =  localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if(visita == 'true'){
        $("#edit-submit-teste").hide();
    }

    $("#views-exposed-form-teste-page").submit(function(e){
        localStorage.setItem('visited', 'true');
        $('option:selected', this).attr('name', "bananinha");
    });
```

Para tentar contornar isso, escrevi no mesmo script que toda vez que o ano ou o mês mudasse, o botão voltaria das cinzas. O probema é que quando o usuário voltasse para um ano que ja havia sido submetido o botao aparecia mesmo assim.

Então, ali no codigo acima, quando a form fosse submetida adicionei um nome para a opção que estava selecionada no ato. Mas falhei porque toda vez que da um refresh na página o name some.

```
 $("#edit-field-de-value-value-year").change(function(){
        var attr = $('option:selected').attr('name');
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            $("#edit-submit-teste").hide();
        }else{
            $("#edit-submit-teste").show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Então, ali no codigo acima, quando a form fosse submetida adicionei um
>   nome para a opção que estava selecionada no ato. Mas falhei porque
>   toda vez que da um refresh na página o name some

Isso não funciona, porque o JavaScript não vai manter a sua mudança, ao fechar o browser e reabrir.

Você poderia armazenar mais informações no Storage, como o mês/ano que o botão foi clicado, então, ao carregar a página, verifique o mês/ano atual, para saber se já existe no storage.

```
var visita =  localStorage.getItem('visited');
if(visita == 'FEB2017'){
  $("#edit-submit-teste").hide();
}
```